# Serilog Request logging is not outputting endpoint data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I started setting up my project to use Serilog Request logging using [this tutorial](https://andrewlock.net/using-serilog-aspnetcore-in-asp-net-core-3-reducing-log-verbosity/). I see the message that I log before calling the `CreateHostBuilder()` method, but according to the article, the console should show the endpoints and HTTP requests. However, none of that is showing. I've tried both Kestrel and IIS Express. I'm not sure what's going on.

I suspect the problem has something to do with my Startup.cs file, as the app I'm working with (GrandNode) is different from the example app in the tutorial. Here is the `Configure()` method from Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
            {
                application.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
                application.ConfigureRequestPipeline(webHostEnvironment);
            }
```

Here is my Main method in Program.cs:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .WriteTo.Console()
                    .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")
                    .CreateLogger();
                try
                {
                    Log.Information("Starting up host 555");
                    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
                }
                finally
                {
                    Log.CloseAndFlush();
                }
            }
```

Any help here would be great!

Comment: Have you tried moving the order of registrations of your middleware in the Configure method. Order is important as request go through the middleware in order of registration and then the order reverses on the way out. I'm not sure what ConfigureRequestPipeline is supposed to do. 

Could you also show the rest of your Configure and ConfigureServices

Comment: From the document, we can see that by using your code, you will get a clean set of request logs containing summary data for each request, if you want to check the detail Information-level log messages, try to remove the `.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)`. Besides, please remember to add the`.UseSerilog()` method in the `CreateHostBuilder` method.